# apexchart combine rangebar with another type or with a full chart marker

Tags: apexcharts

I have a rangeBar type apexchart with the x-axis as datetime and now i want to add vertical lines on specific datetimes or a maker but not only in the bars of athe rangebar but for the whole chart.

I am messing around with different types but none of them seems to work together with my rangebar.

example:
I have a chart bathroom light with On and Off now i also have specific data when a button is pressed and i want to show that on the whole chart, since the bathroom light will not be the only rangeBar type i will show in the chart

```
var options = {
          series: [
          {
name: 'ON',
type: "rangeBar",
            data: [
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 09:17:38.907 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 09:22:42.805 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 09:23:22.027 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 09:23:22.945 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 09:23:22.945 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:21:25.496 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:21:25.496 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:21:27.982 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:21:27.982 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:21:31.215 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:21:31.228 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:55:32.412 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 16:39:04.897 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 16:40:00.655 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 16:40:09.827 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 20:53:25.761 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 20:57:01.283 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 03 07:02:00.033 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 03 07:40:45.737 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 03 20:11:41.794 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 03 20:20:29.057 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 04 07:36:11.949 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 04 07:46:44.230 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 04 16:18:44.298 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 04 16:48:40.449 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 04 19:21:18.655 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 04 19:21:19.756 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 04 19:21:20.412 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 04 19:21:21.218 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 04 19:21:22.118 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 04 19:45:35.932 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 05 05:44:22.720 UTC").getTime(),]},
            ]
          },
          {
            name: 'Off',
            type: "rangeBar",
            data: [
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 09:22:42.805 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 09:23:22.027 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 09:23:22.945 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 09:23:22.945 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:21:25.496 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:21:25.496 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:21:27.982 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:21:27.982 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:21:31.215 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:21:31.228 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 10:55:32.412 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 16:39:04.897 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 16:40:00.655 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 16:40:09.827 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 02 20:53:25.761 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 02 20:57:01.283 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 03 07:02:00.033 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 03 07:40:45.737 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 03 20:11:41.794 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 03 20:20:29.057 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 04 07:36:11.949 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 04 07:46:44.230 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 04 16:18:44.298 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 04 16:48:40.449 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 04 19:21:18.655 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 04 19:21:19.756 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 04 19:21:20.412 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 04 19:21:21.218 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 04 19:21:22.118 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 04 19:45:35.932 UTC").getTime(),]}, 
{x: 'Bathroom - light',y: [new Date("2024 Feb 05 05:44:22.720 UTC").getTime(),new Date("2024 Feb 05 06:06:51.816 UTC").getTime(),]}, 

            ]
          },
        ],
          chart: {
          height: 450,
          type: 'rangeBar'
        },
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: true,
            barHeight: '80%'
          }
        },
        colors: [ // this array contains different color code for each data
            "#66df66",
            "#546E7A",
        ],
        xaxis: {
          type: 'datetime'
        },
        stroke: {
          width: 1
        },
        fill: {
          type: 'solid',
          opacity: 0.6
        },
        legend: {
          position: 'top',
          horizontalAlign: 'left'
        }
        };
    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#room_Bathroom_chart_id"), options);
    chart.render();
```